# OSGi LogService error when deploying apache sling in an app container

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, sling

I am new to sling (and jackrabbit).  I can start the standalone sling instance without any problem.  When I try to deploy the webapp in an app container, I get the following exception in the server.log:

```
ERROR: Error starting slinginstall:org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.2.0.jar (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/log/LogService)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/log/LogService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2496)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2806)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:3693)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1830)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1752)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1156)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.log.LogService not found by org.apache.felix.http.bridge [1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 10 more
```

I am using Java 6.  I get the same error regardless of whether I use JBoss or Glassfish.  I've also tried building the source from the latest subversion checkout and building from the latest official release of the source code.  It seems like it is expecting some sort of logging service (or listener) to be active, but I don't know how to set one up.

Thanks for any help you all can offer!

Comment: I got a quick response from the Sling devlopers.  They made a change to the baseline that cleared up the stack trace shown above.  The war file now deploys without any error -- which is great!  However, http requests to the purported deployment URL return a 404.  I'm waiting for resolution on this next problem before posting the "answer" to this question, in case it's related.  Many thanks for the sling developers for their quick and helpful response.

Comment: FWIW the Sling dev list discussion is at http://markmail.org/thread/3tcis2l3t4sisj5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by an update to the code (revision r1609438) and the problem no longer occurs during deployment of the latest code.  Many thanks to the Apache Sling team for their fast response time!